# UILabel created using Interface Builder wrong origin for the frame

Tags: ios

I am having a very hard time understanding that when I place a UILabel in interface builder and then get the coordinates in my code like this:

```
self.myLabel.frame.origin.x
```

I always get 0. Why is that even though I have placed the UILabel on the center of the screen? How can I get the correct coordinates?

The UILabel is being added to a UIScrollView. The UIScrollView covers the whole iPhone screen 320X480. UIScrollView is added through interface builder.

```
NSLog(@"%f",self.scrollView.bounds.size.height); returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The origin is always relative to the parent view, in your case the `UIScrollView`. The way a `UIScrollView` works is that its contents can have a fixed origin but still appear in different places as the content size and offset (scroll position) are changed.

Furthermore, you did not say anything about the size of your `UILabel`, so it's also possible that the text within is centered but the view itself is much larger.

Also, you don't say where in your code you are checking the coordinates; if you check them too soon they may not yet be set.

Comment: If I turn off Auto layout then everything works as expected! I don't want to turn off Auto Layout.

Comment: @johndoe My guess is then that you are querying the frame before auto layout has run (e.g., `viewDidLoad` is called before auto layout). Try placing the `NSLog` in `viewDidAppear:` and see what it says then…

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are checking it before the label has been added to the view. Try putting a breakpoint somewhere in your code when you can actually see the label on screen and checking the values then.

Comment: The UILabel is being added to a UIScrollView. The UIScrollView covers the whole iPhone screen 320X480. UIScrollView is added through interface builder.  NSLog(@"%f",self.scrollView.bounds.size.height); returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that self.myLabel is not nil, and that you've connected it correctly to your code?  Also that you are loading the view from a xib file and not just using alloc/init on a view...

Answer (score 0):

If non of the previous answers solved your problem,

Make sure you connect the label from the interface builder with its IBOutlet  in the interface header file in your case the header should contain

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIlabel* myLabel;
```

and connected from the interface connector correctly with this property